# How to stop Scroll in a div element?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I don't know how to tell the script that it has reached the bottom, and completed the scrolling cycle. Loading elements during scrolling is accompanied by JS.

Here is the script itself:

```js
await page.evaluate(async () => {
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var totalHeight = 0;
    var distance = 100;
    var timer = setInterval(() => {
      let leftSideBar = document.querySelector('div.scroll__container');
      leftSideBar.scrollTo(0, leftSideBar.scrollHeight);
      totalHeight += distance;

      if (totalHeight >= leftSideBar) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        resolve();
      }
    }, 200);
  });
});
```

Comment: Maybe try using `scrolldown.scrollHeight`?

Comment: Should the totalHeight >= leftSideBar be totalHeight>=leftSideBar.scrollHeight

Comment: @vishnusandhireddy thanks decided